# reading preference value

Tags: java, android

i am working on android and trying to read a value from my preference file.
but when i run.a message appears in emulator.the
**the application has stopped unexpectedly**
here is my preference file name pref.and it is inres/xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <CheckBoxPreference android:defaultValue="false"
             android:key="@string/first"/>
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

this is main activity where i am reding the value.

```
package code.finalwork;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class FinalWorkActivity extends Activity {
    private String pref_file="pref.xml";
EditText text=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        SharedPreferences pref=getSharedPreferences(pref_file,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       Boolean val= pref.getBoolean("firstuse", true);
       if(val)
       {
            text.setText("first use");
       }
       else
       {
           text.setText("Not first use");
       }


    }
}
```

please someone figure out the problem.

Comment: Well firstly you should run it in debug mode.  Keep an eye on logcat and for fatal exception which happens with any crash like this. It will show you the line number that caused it. Click on this an go to that line.

Comment: I'm down voting your question because you should always include the stacktrace information and frankly try to examine it yourself.

Comment: Also you the not getting value in Pref file ... what value are you getting?

Comment: Also I am downvoting because you did not upvote an answer that allows you to find the answer yourself.  Sooner or later you will have other errors, null pointer exceptions.  You first want to look at the crash log.  It would tell you what was null and your question would then be:

Comment: Good chance you would figure this out yourself at this point too.  Its better to spend some time on the techniques to debug and observe your code.

Comment: Not learning the debugger is the biggest mistake you can make in programming.

Comment: that is not good i didnot upvote the answer bcz i was just getting the error.now i got it right and so i am upvoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class FinalWorkActivity extends Activity {
    private String pref_file="pref.xml";
    EditText text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        SharedPreferences pref=getSharedPreferences(pref_file,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean val= pref.getBoolean("firstuse", true);
        if(val) {
        text.setText("first use");
        } else {
        text.setText("Not first use");
        }
    }
}
```

If it doesn't fix please post the error log.

EDIT: remember that so save preferences you need to do:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(pref_file,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();          
editor.putBoolean("firstuse", authToken);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: one more problem it is not reading the default value from pref file.

Comment: Are you sure you are saving them correctly? check out my edit.

Comment: Your code wasn't working because you where instantiating and EditText outside the onCreate method, and the view R.id.editText1 wasn't defined yet.

Comment: How do you know its not reading the default value?  Is it named exactly the same.  Generally repost new questions.

Answer (score 3):

initialize the text (which is EditText ) inside  onCreate function after setContentView .

put this line after `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

```
EditText text=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Comment: This answer is correct.  However you should always post your question with the stack trace.  Always look first at the stack trace viewable in logcat view in eclipse. This would have given you more information.

Comment: yup that worked.But on more problem ,it is not reading the value stored in pref file.

Comment: what is entry @string/first in string.xml  can you confirm me?

Comment: Be specific.  Its not getting the value is not enough information.

Comment: i got it right.the problem was i was not changing the default value in m code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could discover the answer to something like this yourself.  Go to window->showview->logcat

Click on the line in red:

> E/AndroidRuntime(333): at com.test.testing.YourActivityName.(TesterActivity.java:11) 06-15 11:59:05.616:

You would see in red:

```
06-15 11:59:05.526: W/dalvikvm(333): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x40015560)
06-15 11:59:05.616: E/AndroidRuntime(333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 11:59:05.616: E/AndroidRuntime(333): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.test.testing/com.test.testing.TesterActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 11:59:05.616: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
06-15 11:59:05.616: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-15 11:59:05.616: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-15 11:59:05.616: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-15 11:59:05.616: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-15 11:59:05.616: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-15 11:59:05.616: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-15 11:59:05.616: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 11:59:05.616: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-15 11:59:05.616: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-15 11:59:05.616: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-15 11:59:05.616: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-15 11:59:05.616: E/AndroidRuntime(333): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 11:59:05.616: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
06-15 11:59:05.616: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.test.testing.TesterActivity.<init>(TesterActivity.java:11)
06-15 11:59:05.616: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-15 11:59:05.616: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
06-15 11:59:05.616: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
06-15 11:59:05.616: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
06-15 11:59:05.616: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  ... 11 more
```